# Split input and run awk command in parallel

Tags: powershell, shell, awk, sh

I have the following input file :

```
//The values in topics.txt file below are "topicName: partitions: replication-factor" 
// The file has 200 such entries

$ cat /tmp/topics.txt
topic1:1:1
topic2:1:2
```

I want to execute the below awk topic creation command:

```
$ awk -F':' '{ system("./bin/kafka-topics.sh --create --zookeeper localhost:2181 --topic=" $1 " --partitions=" $2 " --replication-factor=" $3) }' /tmp/topics.txt


//output 
Created topic "topic1". 
Created topic "topic2".
```

The above awk command is sequential and takes a lot of time to run and create topics, hence looking for
a way to execute the above script either in parallel or split the input file data into chunks of size 20 and run each chunk in parallel so that performance can be optimized ( currently topics creation with the above command takes over 10 minutes we want to bring it under a minute) , looking for a powershell script or solution which can execute both in windows and linux.

Comment: possible duplicate question, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20308443/parallel-processing-in-awk

Comment: If the bottleneck is topic creation and initial config replication in Kafka, then running the topic creation script in parallel is not going to help, it'll likely just create more overhead

Comment: The Awk script simply runs a shell command so Awk is basically entirely superfluous here. `while IFS=: read -r topic partn rf; do ./bin/kafka-topics.sh --create --zookeeper localhost:2181 --topic="$topic " --partitions="$partn" --replication-factor="$3"; done </tmp/topics.txt`